# weird error with atrribute not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

Have a piece of code when run from the repl generates an weird error on win 7

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import time
from urllib import request

def millis():
  return int(round(time.time() * 1000))

def http_get(url):
  start_time = millis()
  result = {"url": url, "data": request.urlopen(url, timeout=5).read()[:100]}
  print(url + " took " + str(millis() - start_time) + " ms")
  return result



start_time = millis()
if __name__ == "__main__":
  urls = ['http://www.google.com/', 'https://foursquare.com/', 'http://www.yahoo.com/', 'http://www.bing.com/', "https://www.yelp.com/"]
  pool = Pool(processes=5)
  results = pool.map(http_get, urls)
  print("\nTotal took " + str(millis() - start_time) + " ms\n")
  for result in results:
    print(result)
```

And the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "c:\python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "c:\python36\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 345, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'http_get' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I have no clue what i am doing wrong .Without multiprocessing it works like charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html):

> Note
>
> Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.